# Finding possibility of occurrence of words in a document using bloom filter

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, bloom-filter

I have a list of words like - list1 = [boy, apple, mango, car] and I have two documents with following content:

```
document1= The boy driving a car ate apple and mango.
document2= The boy ate an apple.
```

I just need to find out if the given list of words exist in the document.

In order to check if the words in list1 exist in document I can create a bloom filter for list1 (say bloomlist1) and a bloom filter for document1 (say bloomdocument1). Then I can perform bitwise anding and check if the result is same as bloomlist1. If its same, I can say that all words in list1 exist in document1. So, it will return True.

If I do the same approach for document2 i.e. do bitwise anding, then the result will be False. But I need to get True as a result even if a single word on the list is contained in the document.

Is this possible with bloom filter or do I need any other data structure. If no, what can be the best data structure which fulfills both the criteria.

Comment: [Bloom filters can return false positives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter#Probability_of_false_positives).  If the bitwise AND succeeds, you would still need to check that the words were really present.

Comment: False positive is not a problem for me now. I have millions of documents and bloom filter will filter out them for me and later I can simply check if they are really present. I just want to know about if Bloom filter can address the issue that I had for document2. If not, I want to know about any other data structure that can be suitable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think your use of Bloom filters is appropriate.

You state that two filters need to
be constructed, one for the word list and another one for the document being searched. Then you 
bitwise AND the filters. If the result is the same as the original word list filter the
document is accepted, otherwise you reject it.

If this is a correct understanding of your process it is quite clear that a document can only pass
if it contains all of the words from the list (or by means of hash collisions a few extra bits were
set in the document Bloom filter which might cause its acceptance - possibly resulting in a false positive).

If you want to select a document as soon as one word from the list is matched, you only need one Bloom filter for the word list (none for the document being tested). Hash each word from the document, one by one, using the Bloom filter hash functions. Accept the document as soon as the resulting hash matches on all corresponding bits in the word list Bloom filter (this is a hit). You then need to verify that the hit was not due
to a false positive.

The "beauty" of a Bloom filter is that it does not suffer from false negatives. That is, if the none of the
words from your document have a "hit" in the Bloom filter you can be 100 percent sure that none of the
words in the document occur in the associated word list.

One problem you are facing is that Bloom filters are prone to false
positives. A false positive is when there is a hit on the Bloom filter for a word not in the associated list. 
Because of this, you must
explicitly verify the "truth" of every hit using the actual word list whenever the Bloom filter indicates a "hit".
There is no way around it.

The "art" in constructing a good Bloom filter is to find a set of hashing functions that are cheap to
execute and lead a low false positive hit rate (generally this equates to independence and good distribution among
the hash functions). A quick [google search](https://www.google.ca/#q=bloom+filter+) on
Bloom filters will give you plenty of guidance with respect to how many hash functions and how large the filter
needs to be to achieve a given false positive rate (assuming good hashing functions).

If you do the calculations you will find that for a word list of any significant size you will need to use at
least 7 hash functions to achieve an acceptable false-positive rate. Running 7 hash functions against every
word in a large document is going to be "expensive" no matter how you do it. Furthermore, if your documents
contain a large number of different words the probablilty of suffering a false positive hit on the Bloom filter
may become significant - decreasing its usefulness.

Other answers here suggest that a better approach would be to construct a simple hash table for words in the list then hash each word
from the document to see if it has a hit in the list. If so, select the document. Simple. This technique
will most likely out perform the Bloom filter approach for this type of application unless there are some
very special circumstances you have not outlined in your question.

**EDIT** - *What is the best approach?*

There are many ways of doing multi string searches on a given text. It is
difficult to say which one is going to be the best solution for your application because most algorithms and
their implementations are sensitive to complicating factors (eg. average word size, number of
distinct words, document size, number of words in the search list, available memory, probability of having a "hit", etc.). There is no one correct answer here.

Using a Bloom filter may very well be a reasonable approach, however, you should at least look at
other alternatives. A few examples might be:

- [Suffix Trees](http://bio.informatics.indiana.edu/sunkim/c/s06/I690/aomtp.pdf) which can be very efficient for moderately sized word lists.
- [Compact encoding schemes](http://bio.informatics.indiana.edu/sunkim/c/s06/I690/aomtp.pdf) for multi-string matching
- [Hybrid algorithms combining Bloom filters plus a Suffix Tree](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~jignesh/publ/sigmatch.pdf) can also be very efficient
- And, if you can make some simplifying assumptions, such as patterns to match have the same length, something like [this](http://webglimpse.net/pubs/TR94-17.pdf) could be useful

The bottom line is you should look at a wider range of strategies before settling on any specific solution.

Comment: I would like the searching to be done in real-time. Its a web-search application. So, what can be the best approach that can work for my program?

Answer (score 2):

To check whether **any** of the words in the list exist in the document:

- Create a bloom filter.
- Insert all the words in the list into it.
- Then check whether each word in the document is contained in the bloom filter. As soon as you find one, you can return true. If you don't find one, return false.

A bloom filter of course has a possibility of false positives - it can return true even if the word doesn't exist. To avoid this, you can use a hash table instead (in the same way as described above) - this would use a bit more memory though.

Comment: How can we do this? -> "check whether each word in the document is contained in the bloom filter"

Comment: @SudipKafle Well, to insert into a bloom filter, you'll set some of the bits. To check whether an item is already inserted, you simply need to check whether all of those bits are set.

Comment: So, how can we determine which bit would be used by the particular item in the bloom filter?

Comment: You feed the word into a few hash functions - each of these give you a bit position. To insert, you set all those bits. To check whether it's already there, check all those bits. This is the basics of how a bloom filter works (it really only supports those 2 operations) and I probably can't explain it better than some introduction to bloom filters, such as [this](http://www.adayinthelifeof.nl/2012/04/09/bloom-filters/) or [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter).

Comment: Checking for each and every word doesn't seem to be possible as it takes a lot of time and there are thousands of such documents to check. Any idea on how this can be done efficiently with bloom filter or any other data structure?

Comment: @SudipKafle, You're going to have to scan these documents anyhow, you can't match something you don't know. The question is how expensive is your data structure in terms of timing and size - I think a bloom filter should be at the top of the list for both.

Comment: @Leeor As I have mentioned, Bloom filter seems to be unsuitable for me when only some words in the list are in the document. I just want something that can return true even when a single word in list is in the document.

Comment: @SudipKafle: The problem is not in bloom filter per se but in your understanding and usage of it.

Answer (score 2):

If you're searching millions of documents for occurrences of a known set of words, then a Bloom filter is not the best choice. You end up doing an insert into the Bloom filter for every word in each document, and for each document you end up having to check the Bloom filter for each word to determine if it existed in the document.

If all you need to know is whether any one of your words exists in a document, you can build a hash table of the words you want to check, and test each word in the document. So, for example:

```
hashTable = {"boy", "mango", "car", "apple"}
for each document
{
    found = false
    for each word in document
    {
        if word in hash table
        {
            found = true
            break  // found a word. Skip the rest of the document.
        }
        if found then output success else output failure
    }
}
```

This will be better than the Bloom filter approach for several reasons:

- A hash table lookup will in general be faster than setting multiple bits in a Bloom filter.
- With the hash table you can skip much of a document if you find that it contains one of the words.
- You only have to initialize the hash table once. You'd have to clear the Bloom filter for each document.
- The size of your required Bloom filter will depend on the number of unique words in a document. If your Bloom filter is too small then the rate of false positives can be unreasonably high.

Comment: I would like the searching to be done in real-time. Its a web-search application. So, would this approach work for my program?

Comment: @SudipKafle: Without more information about your application, I can't say whether this would be the way to go. I suspect, though, that if you're doing something like a search engine, what you really want is an [inverted index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index). That will give you much faster search. It will also be much more flexible.

Comment: Inverted Index is something I tried at first. After exploring many possibilities, I think its ultimately the best approach.